# Microphone channel not detected in Unity

Tags: unity, audio

This is very specific to Unity.

A few testers are reporting that their microphone output isn't being detected. The code below works for the vast majority of users, but certain microphones seem to be outputting on the wrong channel (R maybe)?

```
 AudioClip current_microphone_recording_clip = Microphone.Start(microphone_name, true, 30, 16000);
```

How can I capture and analyze output from several channels? I don't see any channels parameter for Microphone.Start

Comment: Do you observe anything different about the contents of the `Microphone.devices` array or the current `UserAuthorization.Microphone` setting for these users?

Comment: The microphone array is populated, but the audioclip is just empty. This was on Windows, so UserAuthorization.Microphone wasn't necessary (I think it's only necesary for mobile and iOS)

Comment: And what is it populated with?